# curl --upload-file does not work with alpine

Tags: docker, curl, containers, alpine-linux

I am trying to upload files to [Sonatype Nexus, using their API](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-files-into-Nexus-3-) :

```
curl -v -u admin:admin123 \
   --upload-file pom.xml \
   http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/1.0/foo-1.0.pom
```

This works like a charm with curl runs from **Ubuntu** based container.

However, it does not work well with **Alpine** based container. Indeed, the file URL is created, but the uploaded file is empty ( 0 bytes ) .

is curl syntax different from platform to another?

If so, what's the right syntax with Alpine to call curl with `--upload-file` option ?

Comment: Which alpine version do you run? Which curl version is installed?

Comment: good question. alpine:3.8 .. It seems I need alpine:edge . Let me check

Comment: edge is not stable / moving target. Please try again with 3.10, the latest stable release.